# Adding unused column combinations to DataFrame

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, subset

I have the following dataset:

```
print(df)

  Date      Product_Code     Quantity_ordered
01/01/18         01                 6
02/01/18         04                 3
03/01/18         01                 4
...
```

I would like to create an additional column "Order",using Pandas that, for **each product** and **day**, is equal to 1 if there is a quantity ordered, else 0; for instance:

```
print(final_df)

  Date      Product_Code          Order
01/01/18         01                 1
01/01/18         04                 0

02/01/18         04                 1
02/01/18         01                 0    

03/01/18         01                 1
03/01/18         04                 0
...
```

I tried:

```
a = pd.date_range(min(df["Date"]), max(df["Date"]))
final_df = pd.merge(df, a, on = ["Date", "Product_Code"])
```

But it reports an error saying that it cannot deal with datetime; furthermore, I don't think it's the most efficient way and I don't know how to create the final binary variable.

Regards

Comment: I know my answer was late, but do also look at the alternative :).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`reindex`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.reindex.html) by `unique` values of `Date` and `Product_Code`, what create `NaN`s for missing rows, so possible check by `notnull` and cast to `0,1`:

```
mux = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([df['Date'].unique(), df['Product_Code'].unique()], 
                                 names=('Date','Product_Code'))

df1 = (df.set_index(['Date','Product_Code'])['Quantity_ordered']
        .reindex(mux)
        .notnull()
        .astype(int)
        .reset_index()
        .rename(columns={'Quantity_ordered':'Order'}))
```

Alternative solution is use [`unstack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.unstack.html) for reshape - `NaN`s are added, then check it and cast to `0,1`, last for convert back use [`stack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html):

```
df1 = (df.set_index(['Date','Product_Code'])['Quantity_ordered']
         .unstack()
         .notnull()
         .astype(int)
         .stack()
         .reset_index(name='Order')
)
```

---

```
print (df1)
       Date Product_Code  Order
0  01/01/18           01      1
1  01/01/18           04      0
2  02/01/18           01      0
3  02/01/18           04      1
4  03/01/18           01      1
5  03/01/18           04      0
```

Solution working with duplicates:

```
print (df)
       Date Product_Code  Quantity_ordered
0  01/01/18           01                 6
1  01/01/18           01                 7
2  02/01/18           04                 3
3  03/01/18           01                 4

from  itertools import product
df1 = pd.DataFrame(list(product(df['Date'].unique(), df['Product_Code'].unique())),
                                columns=('Date','Product_Code'))

print (df1)
       Date Product_Code
0  01/01/18           01
1  01/01/18           04
2  02/01/18           01
3  02/01/18           04
4  03/01/18           01
5  03/01/18           04

df2 = pd.merge(df, df1, how='right').sort_values(['Date','Product_Code'])
df2 = (df2.rename(columns={'Quantity_ordered':'Order'})
         .assign(Order=lambda x:x['Order'].notnull().astype(int)))
print (df2)
       Date Product_Code  Order
0  01/01/18           01      1
1  01/01/18           01      1
4  01/01/18           04      0
5  02/01/18           01      0
2  02/01/18           04      1
3  03/01/18           01      1
6  03/01/18           04      0
```

Comment: It reports: "Index contains duplicate entries, cannot reshape" or " cannot handle a non-unique multi-index!" @jezrael

Comment: You're Great! @jezrael

Answer (score 0):

Convert to categories and apply a `groupby.sum`. This retrieves the Cartesian product of your categories, which is what you are looking for.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'Date': ['01/01/18', '02/01/18', '03/01/18'],
                   'Product_Code': ['01', '04', '01'],
                   'Quantity_ordered': [6, 3, 4]})

# Convert to categories
df['Date'] = df['Date'].astype('category')
df['Product_Code'] = df['Product_Code'].astype('category')

# Groupby categories to retrieve cartesian product
df = df.groupby(['Date', 'Product_Code'], as_index=False)['Quantity_ordered'].sum()

# Define Order column
df['Quantity_ordered'] = df['Quantity_ordered'].notnull().astype(int)
```

**Result**

```
       Date Product_Code  Quantity_ordered
0  01/01/18           01                 1
1  01/01/18           04                 0
2  02/01/18           01                 0
3  02/01/18           04                 1
4  03/01/18           01                 1
5  03/01/18           04                 0
```